# Formula Help (Month's Total, Between Two Dates)

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying to generate a report that will show that month's total gas billed. I have two excel sheets in the same document.

The goal is to total a month's gas billing at a specific location for that month.

Conditions in the formula are Location Name, Beginning of the month, and end of the month.

```
=SUMIFS(Data!M:M,Data!L:L,"Olive Branch",">="&C3,'Data'!F:F,"<="&EOMONTH(C3,0))
```

This formula above is the formula not working for me. I am not sure what I can change. I've tried to mimic resources online the best that I could, but I'm missing something. This data is coming from an Excel form that I created as well.

- Column M is Receipt Total.
- Column L is Location.
- C3 is The month criteria on the front sheet.
- Column F is the purchase date of the gas

Front Sheet

[image]

Data Table

[image]

Including rest of data table

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to reference the Data!F:F range for each check against the date range, but the formula you gave only did this once.

=SUMIFS(Data!M:M,Data!L:L,"Olive Branch",Data!F:F,">="&C3,Data!F:F,"<"&EDATE(C3,1))

Comment: That was the answer. I needed to reference my sheet with all the data and dates on it twice when searching for the criteria between the two dates.